# how to sort list order in index view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am using mvc, i want to retrieve the list of values in my index view based on date order descending.  But by using the following LINQ  query am not able to get it in the order by date.

```
var cn = from a in db.table1 
         join b in db.table2 on a.Country equals b.CountryCode
         join c in db.table3 on a.DealerId equals b.CompID  
         order by a.date desc select a;

return View(cn.ToList());
```

Comment: I think you need the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409692/sorting-a-listt-object-in-mvc-view-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code what you are using is correct if you are using normal index view for your view.
But if you are using datatables or some other third party tools, you need to check your code to sort there only.

Comment: Thanks am using datatables only, and i got solution in datatables

Answer (score 0):

Just after you parse the query to a list you can sort it. Just like this:

```
var cn = from a in db.table1 
         join b in db.table2 on a.Country equals b.CountryCode
         join c in db.table3 on a.DealerId equals b.CompID  
         order by a.date desc select a;

var modelToView = cn.ToList().OrderByDescending(t => t.date);
return View(modelToView);
```

Comment: I think there is no problem with my Linq. iam using datatable, it is not allowing the list  to sort.